# Passing Table Value Parameter to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I'v been searching and changing code for hours, but couldn't find topic with problem I am facing and my changes doesn't seem to help.

Sql type for TVP:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MessagesIds] AS TABLE(
[msgId] [nvarchar](500) NULL)
```

Procedure:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[DeleteMessagesByIds] 
@SocialMediaType nvarchar(50),
@MsgIds dbo.MessagesIds READONLY
As 
Begin
    DECLARE @TypeId int
    SELECT @TypeId = ID FROM SocialMediaType WHERE Title = @SocialMediaType

    Set NOCOUNT ON;
    DELETE FROM [Message]
    Where ID In 
    (Select B.ID From [Message] B 
    Inner Join @MsgIds msgsToDeleteIds On B.id_str = msgsToDeleteIds.msgId
    Where B.SocialMediaTypeID = @TypeId);
END
```

C# procedure calling code:

```
var idsTable = new DataTable();
idsTable.Columns.Add("msgId", typeof(string));
foreach (var id in ids) { //ids = List<string>
  idsTable.Rows.Add(id);
}
var socialMediaTypeParameter = new SqlParameter("@SocialMediaType", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
socialMediaTypeParameter.Value = socialMediaType;
var idsParameter = new SqlParameter("@MsgIds", SqlDbType.Structured);
idsParameter.Value = idsTable;
idsParameter.TypeName = "dbo.MessagesIds";
context.Database.Log = s => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s); }; 
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec dbo.DeleteMessagesByIds @SocialMediaType @MsgIds", socialMediaTypeParameter, idsParameter);
```

I receive error: `Incorrect syntax near '@MsgIds'` when executing sql command. In debug console I see that in the generated sql @MsgIds is empty, but why?

```
exec dbo.DeleteMessagesByIds @SocialMediaType @MsgIds
-- @SocialMediaType: 'Facebook' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 8)
-- @MsgIds: '' (Type = Object, IsNullable = false)
-- Executing at 2015.09.08. 16:05:52 +03:00
```

Comment: This certainly *looks* like [tag:sql-server] syntax, and, so far as I'm aware, [tag:mysql] doesn't *have* table-valued parameters. Have you tagged this question correctly?

Comment: How absolutely sure are you that ids is not empty? Can you debug log ids.Count() to be sure?

Comment: Looking again - are you not just missing a comma between the two parameters?

Comment: Yes, I added mysql tag incorrectly, sorry. Fixed now. And yes, I was missing a comma, I actually was sure that I don't need a comma there... Got messed up with the syntax. Thanks!